# application level HA available with Linux HeartBeat..?

Tags: linux, high-availability, heartbeat

I was trying to understand how Linux-HA project, Heartbeat actually works. I found out that Heartbeat provides HA at a system level rather than application level, meaning the Virtual IP is move to backup system only on a system-down-scenario and not when application goes down. I verified this. I had configured `httpd` in my `haresources` file and I manually stopped httpd using `service httpd stop`. although this stops httpd service, Heartbeat doesn't recognize this.

But when I stop heartbeat or bring down my machine, Backup comes up and starts httpd. Is this the correct scenario.. if not, please let me know why I should provide a script in `resources.d/` to start, stop and find status of the application. Also, how can I achieve application level HA using heartbeat..!

Thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, heartbeat will only check the other machine is reachable or not.

2) If you want to monitor a service and has to start backup server when the other service is down, you need to write a script for it and need to start the script when machine boot up. You should keep on monitor the service and if the service is not running stop heartbeat service.

3) Heartbeat will not monitor any service like (For example java/.net application/Http server).